# How to use Azure Kusto Query Language (KQL) to query Jmeter Graph such as Active Threads Over times

Tags: azure, jmeter, azure-application-insights, kql

If Jmeter already connect to Azure(like  JMeter logs sent to a platform
like Log Analytics workspace) , you get all Jmeter data you want. You can easily use KQL to query the Jmeter data.
But you just don't know how to query Jmeter Graph - Active Threads Over times

Is there any Query code for it? Thanks

Comment: It's not clear where your challenge is.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz thanks. is now clearly enough? I need a query code to find  Jmeter Graph such as Active Threads Over times

Comment: We have no context to your question. Were you able to connect Jmeter to Azure or not? To what Service? Are you able to see the data flowing? Are you familiar with the tables or you are trying to understand which is the relevant table? Have you found the table but you are not sure regarding the relevant fields? Do you know your data well but you never used KQL before? Have you used KQL but haven't used the time series functionality?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz Thanks David. is now clear enough ? do you know the KQL to generate Graph - Active Threads Over times? thanks

Comment: I understand that you already have the data in Log Analytics. Could you share a data sample?

Comment: P.S. you have some related code example in the following links.. Not exactly your scenario but can give you some leads. (1) https://blog.pnop.co.jp/jmeter-aggregate-graph-application-insights-log-analytics_en/  (2) https://blog.pnop.co.jp/jmeter-response-time-graph-application-insights-log-analytics_en/

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm Charlie from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team. I'm not usually here, so may not see a follow up question, but do want help.

KQL is used to query telemetry and logs from technologies based on Azure Data Explorer (i.e,Application Insights, Logs Analytics workspace, Search in Sharepoint).

This said, you must have your JMeter logs sent to a platform like Log Analytics workspace before you can continue to query them. If you have, please follow these link to learn how to interact with that workspace in Azure:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-query-overview
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-analytics-tutorial

To help you further, please include how you connected JMeter Logs to Azure.

Comment: This said, you must have your JMeter logs sent to a platform like Log Analytics workspace before you can continue to query them.   Thanks Charlie. Do you know how to query the  Active Threads Over times then? Thanks